# Google crawls my website too slowly

Tags: google, web-crawlers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I think Google crawls it too slowly (every three days). I updated it daily and it's kind of frustrating.

Should I build more backlinks? The robots.txt looks ok.

Answer (score 2):

Google visiting you every three days is not bad at all for a new site with almost no authority and backlinks.

I checked your domain on opensiteexplorer.org and sistrix.com and it's almost non-existent.

Set up Google Webmastertools and you'll have quick feedback about site problems. Do the same on Bing.

Just keep producing good content, verify your numbers in Google Analytics and increase relevant traffic for your site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll just have to add content that matters to searches. As you add more content, your website will be crawled more frequently.

If your site runs well (technically speaking) and your text is easy to index for Google, you should not have much trouble increasing your indexing frequency. Google will inform you if there are problems with your site if you sign up for Google Webmaster Tools and link your site to your account.

If you want more info with further tips, check out this site http://www.markethealth.com/articles/view/10_ways_to_increase_google_indexing.php.